# Internet Explorer adding an extra line break

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, line-breaks

I have the following Javascript code:

```
parts[0] + "\n" + parts[1] + "\n" + parts[2] + "\n" + parts[3] + "\n" +parts[4]
```

Which should result in the following on screen

```
Some text
More Text
Text here too
Another Line
Final Line
```

But in Internet Explorer it adds an extra line break so I get:

```
Some text

Why the extra space?

Is it something

IE does

Just to annoy me?!
```

**Update**
Here's a jsfiddle of the code I have: http://jsfiddle.net/hUWFZ/

Comment: Are you sure the parts[] don't contain spaces? Could you place an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: I've just tried to recreate on JSfiddle but can't work out what I'm doing wrong as I don't get anything displayed there. It's annoying me as my code works fine in any other browsers I check. Was just wondering if IE had any known issues that added the extra breaks in!?

Comment: Ah... here we go: http://jsfiddle.net/hUWFZ/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line:

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = ...
```

to use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`.

There is a known issue with Internet Explorer and whitespace in textareas when using innerHTML ([see article for more details](http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e0226430/innerHtmlQuirk.html)).